# import images in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

hi how can i import images in webpack 4?

Here is my Webpack Config. The image is loaded in the static folder but the name is cryptical. If i want to import it and log it out there is only the string with the filename. How can i use it correctly?

[image]

[image]

[image: OUTPUT IMAGE]

**That is how i use it**

```
import img  from "../../../../assets/hallo.png"

<img style = "height: 100px;width: 100px" src="${img}" />
```

**Webpack Config**

```
const path = require('path')
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin")
var webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports  ={
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
    filename: 'monitor-bundle.js'

  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          {
            fallback: 'style-loader',
            use: ['css-loader']
          })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  watch: true,
  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      watchOptions: {
        poll: true
      },
        host: "localhost",
        port: "1337",
        proxy: "http://localhost:80/",
        files: ["./static/monitor-bundle.js"],
        open: true,
        reloadDelay: 0,
        reloadDebounce: 0,
        browser: ["chromium", "google chrome"]
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'monitor-style.css'})
],
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are just passing an empty string as source here.

```
<img style = "height: 100px;width: 100px" src="${img}" />
```

You need to use template string if u want to use this ${}

```
<img style = "height: 100px;width: 100px" src=`${img}` />
```

In this case you can just do this

```
 <img style = "height: 100px;width: 100px" src={img} />
```

Comment: this is not the problem.... i am using a nodeTemplate. `<img style = "height: 100px;width: 100px" src="${img}" />`

Comment: Oh okay. I can imagine that the node template causes this issue as the image path would normally be changed to the image file thats created in your output directory. Oh sorry mb it is referencing the right file.

Comment: how can i test it other way without nodeTemplate?

Comment: Try add publicPath to your output with your output dir as value.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Comment: i dont want my bundle and all assets in the public path

Comment: Can you upload it to codebox that i can reproduce and debug it? I dont use BrowserSync and NodeTemplates so might be related to them, but i cant seem to find it rn. Maybe someone else does tho. I could only figure it out with the code.

Comment: When i log it out there should be the base64 string. But there is only the name

Comment: it does not depend on nodeTemplate or BrowserSync

Comment: Why do you expect the base 64string, if you log it you should get the path. The path of the image in the output directory

Comment: i tried another exmaple without webpack and logged it out. And there was logged out the base64 string

Comment: Yeah but with webpack you import images (instead of just writing the path in the src) that webpack knows it has to put that file in the output dir and then adjust the src to the picture in the ouput dir.
Can you try setting the public path to publicPath: '/' ?

Comment: dont know what you mean... in output? or where?

Comment: yes
output: { 
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'), 
publicPath: '/',
filename: 'monitor-bundle.js' 
},

Comment: Adding `publicPath: '/'` to webpack.config.js works as without it, `file-loader` does not add anything in front of all paths and they become relative. This changes `img/asset.png` to `/img/asset.png`.